# JavaScript - Simple Query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/) code I already have. My issue is that I require to use a radio check **AND** a text entry into a text field to enable other radios, checkboxes and text fields. So far I have only managed to enable radios, checkboxes and text fields using radio option 1 **OR** radio option 2.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/) might help you guys out and give you a greater understanding of what I mean.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class='conlabel'>Have you started trading yet?</div>
  <table width="100">
          <tr>
            <td><label>
              <input type="radio" name="example" value="Yes" id="example_0" required />
              Yes</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
          <input type="radio" name="example" value="No" id="example_1" required />
          No</label></td>
      </tr>
</table><br>
  <li>
      <div class='conlabel'>If Yes, enter trading name:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="" disabled />
  </li><br>
  <li>
  <div class='conlabel'>If No, then:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" placeholder="" disabled />
  </li><br>

<li>
      <div class='conlabel'>Enter trading start date (enabled when started trading yet = yes + trading name = notnull:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" placeholder="" disabled />
 </li><br>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
$("#example_0, #example_1").change(function(){
    $("#field1, #field2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
    if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
        $("#field1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#field1").focus();
    }
    else if($("#example_1").is(":checked")){
        $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#field2").focus();   
    }
});
});
```

In this example the code currently enables and focuses on either field1 **OR** field2 depending on whether they section radio-example_0 or example_1. What I have not been able to figure out is if they select Yes (example_0) and then enter a trading name in field1 how then to enable field3.

Hope this is clearer than my last attempt. Thanks for your help! (:

**Answer:** Kindly donated by [Daniel V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989452/daniel-v).

```
$(function(){
    $("#example_0, #example_1").change(function(){
        $("#field1, #field2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
            if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
            $("#field1").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#field1").focus();
        }
        else if($("#example_1").is(":checked")){
            $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#field2").focus();   
        }
    });
    });

$("#field1").blur(function(){
    if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
             if($("#field1").val()!==""){
                   $("#field3").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show the HTML, please.

Comment: - and even better, put it all in a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @F4r-20 - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/11/)

Comment: @Juhana - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a selector that looks for the checked checkbox and a non-empty text box:

```
if ($('#example1:checked,#textfield1[value!=""]').length == 2) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/rQKRH/

#### Edit:

With that HTML code you can use this to determine if the text box should be enabled:

```
var enable = $('#example_0').is(':checked') && $('#field1').val() != '';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/cEaeK/18/

Comment: sorry my explanation was horrendous. Please check out this link to find out what I mean. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/)

Comment: @PaulArmstrong: I added code for your specific HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I'm understanding you right, but do you mean like this?

```
 if(($("#example1").is(":checked"))&&!$('#input').val()){//do}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WULPL/1/

Comment: sorry my explanation was horrendous. Please check out this link to find out what I mean. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/)

Comment: @PaulArmstrong Seems to me like Guffa and me answered you right then. Now it's up to you to try out how to best sort the functions and get everything working. This page is for giving you the needed basis, not writing your whole code ;) After you've experimented around and still can't get it working, then you can update this thread with the new code and ask us for help again. Don't forget to mark whichever answer you used as right once you're finished.

Comment: @PaulArmstrong How about you being more reasonable? You were given help. So how is it too much to ask for you to try and implement what we've given you? If you can't figure it out after trying to get it to work with the snippets that's one thing, but don't expect other people to hand you everything on a golden platter. How are you supposed to learn from that? And telling us to get a life? That's a pretty rude thing to say to the people trying to help you.

Comment: Im telling you. I didnt mean other people in this particular thread. My point was... I would prefer to attempt to implement every solution on this website rather than ask again to be critised, hence, obviously I already tried to implement the solutions and in fact the one that ended up working was bits of various suggestions. never did I say i expected anything on a "golden platter". I just think instead of being on your high horse being more tolerant, especially to new people. Anyways this is very pointless. thanks for your help

Comment: @PaulArmstrong What high horse? You never showed us any progress implementing anything we suggested, so no, it's not obvious that you tried. So tell me again, how are we supposed to tell you what you did wrong trying to implement those snippets if you don't show us what you've got. Even "new people" should know that without seeing what you tried we can't sustainably help you. Right, think about that before complaining next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#field1").blur(function(){
   if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
            if($("#field1").val()!==""){
                  $("#field3").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });
```