# JavaScript Query - Using AND & OR with Radios, Checkboxes and Text Fields to enable form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/) code I already have. My issue is that I require to use a radio check **AND** a text entry into a text field to enable other radios, checkboxes and text fields. So far I have only managed to enable radios, checkboxes and text fields using radio option 1 **OR** radio option 2.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/) might help you guys out and give you a greater understanding of what I mean.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class='conlabel'>Have you started trading yet?</div>
  <table width="100">
          <tr>
            <td><label>
              <input type="radio" name="example" value="Yes" id="example_0" required />
              Yes</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
          <input type="radio" name="example" value="No" id="example_1" required />
          No</label></td>
      </tr>
</table><br>
  <li>
      <div class='conlabel'>If Yes, enter trading name:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="" disabled />
  </li><br>
  <li>
  <div class='conlabel'>If No, then:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" placeholder="" disabled />
  </li><br>

<li>
      <div class='conlabel'>Enter trading start date (enabled when started trading yet = yes + trading name = notnull:</div>
      <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" placeholder="" disabled />
 </li><br>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
$("#example_0, #example_1").change(function(){
    $("#field1, #field2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
    if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
        $("#field1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#field1").focus();
    }
    else if($("#example_1").is(":checked")){
        $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#field2").focus();   
    }
});
});
```

In this example the code currently enables and focuses on either field1 **OR** field2 depending on whether they section radio-example_0 or example_1. What I have not been able to figure out is if they select Yes (example_0) and then enter a trading name in field1 how then to enable field3.

Hope this is clearer than my last attempt. Thanks for your help! (:

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Simple Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542780/javascript-simple-query)

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of reposting it as a new question.

Comment: People marked it down for some reason so I figured it would get more attention if I re-posted it. Probably because I struggled to explain the issue and find the right terminology. I did edited and didn't get any response.

Comment: when you edit, your question should bump up the list just the same as a new question would.  Nevertheless, exact duplicates are always going to get closed or, most probably in this case, merged.

Comment: Oh I see, just thought the down vote would of put people off for some reason. Thanks

Comment: I made similar beginner mistakes so I'll cast you a couple of upvotes but please close / merge your questions!

Comment: Absolutely Rick, I'll get on that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the value of field1 when the cursor leaves it, try this:

```
  $("#field1").blur(function(){
   if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
            if($("#field1").val()!==""){
                  $("#field3").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/13/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $("#example_0, #example_1").change(function(){
        $("#field1, #field2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
        if($("#example_0").is(":checked")){
            $("#field1").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#field1").focus();
        }
        else if($("#example_1").is(":checked")){
            $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#field2").focus();   
             $("#field3").val('');
                              $("#field3").attr("disabled",true);
        }
    });

        $('#field1').focusout(function(){

            if($('#field1').val().length!=0)
                  $("#field3").removeAttr("disabled");
            else
            { $("#field3").val('');
                              $("#field3").attr("disabled",true);
            }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($("#example0").is(":checked") && $("#field0").val().length != 0) || ($("#example1").is(":checked") && $("#field1").val().length != 0)) {
    PASS!
}
```

Comment: I have attempt to implement this but have been unsuccessful. Probably me and not the code. If you could enter it into the JSFiddle example and repost, it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Yeah its a fiddly one... Although I'd appreciate an upvote, the answer below this looks like its done just that (although I don't know how neccesary the .val('') in the else is), so go with that mate.